# How can i include assets with an Angular Library? (v 8.0)

Tags: angular-library

Is there a way to include assets in an Angular Library, using the latest version of Angular?
I've read some variants, but the answers were for Angular 6 and since then the CLI has improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, now it's possible.

A few days ago, [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) released a new version that allows you to include the assets along with the build files:

**You can copy these assets by using the assets option.**

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "assets": [
      "CHANGELOG.md",
      "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
    ],
    "lib": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

More information here: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md

In resume, if you follow the Angular Documentation on [how create a Library](https://v8.angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) and you include the new [ng-packagr configuration](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md), you will be able to include the css files in the build.